# Existe uma regra para saber qual o plural de palavras terminadas em "ão"?

Tags: número-gramatical, morfologia

Estes dias estive a pensar sobre as possíveis formas do plural de palavras terminadas em *ão* no Português. Consigo lembrar de 3 formas possíveis:

1. Adição de *s*. P.ex. m**ão** --> m**ãos**
2. Troca do *ão* por *ões*. P.ex. lim**ão** --> lim**ões**
3. Troca do *ão* por *ães*. P.ex. alem**ão** --> alem**ães**

À primeira vista é difícil achar um padrão, visto que nos 3 exemplos acima todas as palavras terminam em *mão*, mas possuem plurais distintos. Imagino que haja explicação etimológica para estas diferenças, mas isto não é prático do ponto de vista daqueles que desejam aprender o idioma.

Existe uma regra que determine qual o plural de uma palavra terminada em *ão*?

Comment: Em geral não vai existir uma regra só, precisamente porque a explicação é etimológica. Para mim, o método mais "práctico", para além de memorização, é comparar com a palavra equivalente na língua espanhola. Mas me parece que isto não vai preencher os seus requisitos, porque não é útil para todos.

Comment: @DanGetz Eu estava imaginando como um falante estrangeiro faria para aprender estes plurais. É algo que parece natural para um falante nativo (o plural errado soa estranho), mas sem sentido para quem precisa aprender sem ter uma base maior do idioma. Este tipo de aspectos naturais são comuns em outros idiomas e isso é algo que me incomoda ao (tentar) aprendê-los.

Comment: Parece-me que há ainda uma regra que não vem no Ciberdúvidas: todas as palavras em ***-ção*** e ***-são*** derivadas de verbos forma plural em ***ões***. Não tou a ver nenhuma exceção.

Comment: @gmauch Os tags que escolheste parecem-me duvidosos. Se soubermos como se diz, também sabemos como escrever; portanto não me parece que seja uma questão ortográfica. *Número-gramatical* sugere-me questões de concordância. Por que não simplesmente *plurais*?

Comment: @Jacinto pois é, não fiquei muito satisfeito com as tags que achei. Pensei que _plural_ fosse específica demais e não existiria ainda, porém me enganei! vou editar a questão!

Comment: Pois, *plural/plurais* não existe ainda. É é capaz de facto de ser muito específico. Nem sei se há muitas perguntas que se possam fazer acerca de plurais no português. Somos tão regulares... Não sei se *morfologia*? Não sei ao certo o que é. Vou investigar.

Comment: A tag _plural_ é sinônimo de _número-gramatical_. Eu prefiro plural, acho de uso mais corriqueiro, mas enfim...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Infelizmente não há regra de jeito. Esta [página do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/plural-de-substantivos-terminados-em--ao/5554), transcrevendo a gramática de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra, expõe a questão exaustivamente. O melhor que eu consigo sistematizar a informação é assim:

1. A maioria das palavras formam plural em ***ões***: *balões, trovões, e leões*. Incluem-se aqui todos os aumentativos: *figurões, paspalhões e cabrões*.
2. Esta regra é da minha autoria. Com uma exceção, todas as oxítonas em ***-ção*** e ***-nsão***, muitas, derivadas de verbos, formam plural em ***ões***: *dilatações, exportações, criações, tensões, apreensões, extensões*. A exceção é [*loução*](http://www.aulete.com.br/lou%C3%A7%C3%A3o), cujo plural é *louçãos*.
3. Os monossílabos formam plural em ***ães***, *cães, pães*, ou ***ãos***: *chãos, grãos, mãos, sãos e vãos*. Creio que esta lista é exaustiva.
4. Todos os paroxítonos (palavras acentuadas na penúltima sílaba) formam plural em ***ãos***: *bênçãos, órgãos, orégãos.*
5. Agora, há ainda um conjunto, pouco numeroso, de palavras que formam plural em ***ães*** ou ***ãos*** e que não estão incluidas nos pontos 2 e 3 acima. Por exemplo: *cidadãos, irmãos, cristãos, capitães, bastiães, charlatães*. A página do Ciberdúvidas indicada acima lista mais exemplos, mas fiquei sem perceber se a lista é exaustiva.
6. Finalmente há ainda palavras que aceitam mais que um plural, como por exemplo: *anãos ou anões, corrimãos ou corrimões, anciãos, anciões ou anciães.* Novamente, não percebi se a lista apresentada no Ciberdúvidas é exaustiva.

Esta [outra página do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/plural-de-palavras-terminadas-em-ao/3824) explica que, tal como imaginaste, a forma do plural depende do étimo: *-ãos* vem do latim *-anos*; *-ães*, do latim *-anes* (*canes, panes*); e *-ões*, do latim *-ones*. Depois há ainda palavras que não vêm do latim, como *limão*, que veio do árabe, que tipicamente formam plural com *ões* simplesmente por ser esta a forma mais comum.

Comment: Não é que as palavras como *limão, limões* (e talvez as outras também)  diziam-se *limón, limones* anteriormente?

Comment: @tchrist Encontrei *limoës* e *limoëes* num tratado de cozinha de cerca de 1400. Do mesmo modo encontra-se no século XV *coraçom, coraçon, coraçoes, coraçoões, coraçoens* e *coraçoeens*. Agora se séculos antes se dizia limones, não sei. Nem sei quando é se nasalaram os *-on, -ones* latinos no galaico-português, se terá sido antes da chegada dos limões ou não.

Comment: @Jacinto aqui pelo norte ainda se diz coraçon ;)

Comment: Há outra exceção ao segundo item: *"benção ~ bençãos"*.

Comment: @Seninha, bem observado; ainda por cima eu tenho essa palavra no ponto 4!

Comment: @Seninha, resolvi a questão restringindo o ponto 2 a oxítonas. De facto todas elas o são. Acho.

Comment: Isso é por causa do sufixo "-[c]tionem" que era extremamente produtivo no latim (e é até hoje no Português), que gerou o final oxítono "-ção/-ções". Devido à alta frequência desse sufixo, quase todos os "-ção" do portugês vêm daí. Na verdade, "bênção" também veio deste sufixo, e inclusive há o registro "bênções" em escritos mais antigos, mas a palavra passou a ter o final "-ão/ãos" já depois. Eu falo do caso da "bênção" num parágrafo [desta minha resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/4569/2076).

Answer (score 3):

De uma maneira geral, palavras femininas oxítonas terminadas em "ão" formam plural em "ões":

Solução - soluções

Ilusão - ilusões

Frustração - frustrações

Canção -    canções

A principal exceção é "mão", plural "mãos".

Palavras masculinas oxítonas terminadas em "ão" cujo feminino termina em "oa" ou "ona", que não têm feminino, ou cujo feminino é irregular também formam plural em "ões":

Leão - leoa - leões

Folião - foliona - foliões

Ladrão - ladra - ladrões

Limão - ??? - limões

As principais exceções são "pão", plural "pães", e "cão", plural "cães".

Palavras masculinas oxítonas terminadas em "ão" cujo feminino termina em "ã" formam plural em "ãos" ou "ães":

Artesão - artesã - artesãos

Alemão - alemã - alemães

Anão - anã - anãos (embora esta forma já seja arcaizante, tendo sido substituída por "anões")

Palavras paroxítonas terminadas em "ão" formam plura em "ãos".

Mas são regras aproximativas. A maneira segura de saber o plural correto é olhar o cognato espanhol - se existir, é claro:

Artesão - artisano - artesãos

Mão - mano - mãos

Anão - enano - anãos

Ladrão - ladrón - ladrões

Ilusão - ilusión - ilusões

Pão - pán - pães

Alemão - alemán - alemães

Parece-me que apenas "ões" é ainda produtivo no caso das oxítonas, portanto neologismos ou importações recentes terão plural em "ões":

Enrolação - enrolações

Cupão - cupões

Deletação - deletações

(Outra coisa: não existe "sufixo mão"; em todos os três exemplos citados, o "m" é parte da raiz. Nos casos de "limão" e "alemão", temos o sufixo "ão"; no caso de "mão", não há sufixo.)

Answer (score 2):

Não, a distinção no singular perdeu-se e agora só sabendo a etimologia da palavra.

No entanto se souber a palavra em espanhol é fácil saber o plural em português:

alemán - alemão
alemanes - alemães

mano - mão
manos - mãos

limón - limão
limones - limões

Como se pode observar, em Espanhol se a palavra terminar em *n* adiciona-se *es*, em português isso traduz-se substituindo o *n* por um til na vogal que a precede. Quando a palavra termina em *o*, adiciona-se simplesmente um *s*.

Comment: Interessante a associação com o espanhol, Rui. Qual a fonte desta afirmação? Podes publicá-la junto de sua resposta?

Comment: Qual afirmação?

Comment: Da relação entre a palavra em espanhol e seu plural em português.

Comment: https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/alemão
https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/mão
https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/limão
http://dle.rae.es/?id=1hn1XWS
http://dle.rae.es/?id=OF9CzGo|OFAJXYy
http://dle.rae.es/?id=NKe3QPp|NKe4Hm6