# Vão ou Vam, Como posso usá-los?

Tags: português-brasileiro, ortografia

Em uma conversa com uma amiga eu disse o seguinte:

> Os meninos **vam** querer fazer um dogão (famoso cachorro quente aqui no
>   brasil) hoje.

Aí ela me falou que eu estava errado, e que se poderia diferenciar assim:

- **vão:** futuro
- **vam:** vam (veículo) que  você viaja.

Gostaria de saber quando usar um e outro, tenho dúvidas também sobre `estam` e 
`estão`.

Comment: Você quer saber a diferença entre um carro [van] e um verbo???Acho que o pessoal caiu no poço. Credo.

Comment: @Lambie minha dúvida foi esclarecida na resposta do Hugo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Vam** e **estam** não existem no Português.

A conjugação correta destes verbos é **vão** e **estão**. Então o correto é:

> Os meninos **vão** querer fazer um dogão hoje.
>
> Eles **estão** bem.

Quanto ao [veículo](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=van&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLr6__ttXUAhULipAKHQzuDt0Q_AUICigB&biw=1288&bih=696), a grafia - ao menos no Brasil - é **van**. Não sei exatamente porque se escreve com `n` no final, talvez seja mais um termo em Inglês que acabou não sendo traduzido.

De qualquer forma, há outros nomes para o mesmo, como por exemplo **furgão** e **kombi** (sendo este último uma metonímia com a [Volkswagen Kombi](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Kombi), já que o termo pode ser usado para qualquer veículo similar) - regionalmente também podem ser encontrados outros nomes.

---

> Gostaria de saber quando usar um e outro

De forma resumida:

- **vão** é uma [conjugação verbal](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbo-ir/) (3<sup>a</sup> pessoa do plural, no presente do indicativo, do verbo **ir**)
- **estão** também é uma [conjugação verbal](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbo-estar/) (3<sup>a</sup> pessoa do plural, no presente do indicativo, do verbo **estar**)
- **van** é um substantivo ([um tipo de veículo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van))
- **estam** (ou **estan**) não existe

Talvez sua dúvida venha do fato de que os verbos regulares da primeira conjugação [tem a terminação ***am*** na 3<sup>a</sup> pessoa do plural do presente](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbos-da-primeira-conjugacao-terminados-em-ar/) (como por exemplo **"Eles falam"** e **"Eles cantam"**).

Mas como **ir** e **estar** são verbos irregulares, esta regra não se aplica a eles.

Answer (score 6):

Uma boa forma de compreender quando e por quê se usa ⟨am⟩ ou ⟨ão⟩ é saber de onde estas duas terminações vieram.

O som em final de palavra `/-ãw̃/`, representado na ortografia pelas duas terminações ⟨-am, -ão⟩ (na realidade, pelos 4 grupo de terminações ⟨-am, -ão/ões, -ão/ães, -ão/ãos⟩) possui origem em 3 grupos etimológicos de terminações distintas no Galego-Português (ou Português Antigo); cada uma variando em tonicidade. Estas três terminações eram ⟨-on, -an, -ão⟩. Explicarei cada uma delas com exemplos indicando a evolução da palavra desde a forma latina, à forma em galego-português, até a forma no português moderno.

[image: Evolução das terminações "am/ão"]

### Primeiro grupo etimológico

O primeiro grupo etimológico é formado por palavras que, no galego-português, possuíam a terminação "**-on**" (pronunciada `/õ/`), derivada das terminações latinas "*-on/-ont/-onem, -un/-unt/-unem*". As palavras deste grupo possuíam 4 realizações, das quais todas são atualmente grafadas com ⟨*-ão/-ões*⟩; exceto as polissílabas não-oxítonas, que são atualmente grafadas ⟨-am⟩.

```
                         LATIM         > PT ANTIGO†  > PT MODERNO
Monossílaba tônica:      sunt          > son         > são (verbo, ser)
Monossílaba átona:       non           > non         > não
Polissílaba oxítona:     sermonem      > sermon      > sermão
Polissílaba não-oxítona: fuerunt       > forom/foron > foram (verbo, ir)
```

†A ortografia do galego-português não era regular, e variava de autor para autor, época e lugar.

Exemplos: "sermão/sermões", "ação/ações", "lesão/lesões", etc.

Os raros nomes polissílabos não-oxítonos desta etimologia convergiram com o terceiro grupo etimológico.  Por exemplo, a palavra galego-portuguesa "bẽeiçon", do latim "benedictionem", deveria fazer parte deste grupo etimológico; porém, sua forma moderna "bênção" migrou para o terceiro grupo e comporta-se como tal, tanto ortograficamente (sendo escrita com ⟨-ão⟩) quanto morfologicamente (indo ao plural como "bênçãos", em vez da forma antiga "bênções").

### Segundo grupo etimológico

O segundo grupo etimológico é formado por palavras que, no galego-português, possuíam a terminação "**-an**" (pronunciada `/ã/`), derivada das terminações latinas "*-ant/-anem*" (e raramente "*-am*", somente em monossílabas, creio eu). As palavras deste grupo possuíam 4 realizações, das quais todas são atualmente grafadas com ⟨-ão/ães⟩; exceto as polissílabas não-oxítonas, que são atualmente grafadas ⟨-am⟩.

```
                         LATIM   > PT ANTIGO     > PT MODERNO
Monossílaba tônica:      canem   > cão/can       > cão
Monossílaba átona:       tam     > tam/tan       > tão
Polissílaba oxítona:     stant   > estam/estan   > estão
Polissílaba não-oxítona: cantant > cantam/cantan > cantam
```

Exemplo: "cão/cães", "pão/pães" etc.

Os raros nomes polissílabos desta etimologia convergiram com o terceiro grupo etimológico.  Por exemplo, a palavra galego-portuguesa "refran" deveria fazer parte deste grupo etimológico("-an"); porém, sua forma moderna "refrão" migrou para o terceiro grupo e comporta-se como tal, tanto ortograficamente (sendo escrita com ⟨-ão⟩) quanto morfologicamente (indo ao plural como "refrãos", em vez da forma antiga "refrães").

### Terceiro grupo etimológico

O terceiro grupo etimológico é formado por palavras que, no galego-português, possuíam a terminação "**-ão**" (pronunciada `/ão/`), derivada da terminação latina "*-anum*". As palavras deste grupo possuem 3 realizações, das quais todas são atualmente grafadas com ⟨-ão/ãos⟩, sem exceção.

```
                         LATIM    > PT ANTIGO   > PT MODERNO
Monossílabo tônica:      manum    > mão         > mão
Monossílaba átona†:
Polissílabo oxítona:     germanum > irmão/yrmão > irmão
Polissílaba não-oxítona: organum  > orgam/órgão > órgão
```

† Devido à forma pela qual este grupo etimológico se desenvolveu a partir do latim, não haviam monossílabos átonos nesse grupo.

### Comentários à etimologia

Figuras de linguagem (como por exemplo, na frase "a votação resultou em 40 **nãos**", a substantivação e pluralização de "não") fogem à etimologia. Erros gramaticais, como conjugar advérbios ("As **tãos** sonhadas casas"), também vão além da etimologia.

Apesar de no português padrão todas essas terminações serem todas pronunciadas `/-ãw̃/`, alguns dialetos ainda mantêm a pronuncia de formas históricas.  Por exemplo, o dialeto da costa norte brasileira mantém a pronúncia de monossílabos átonos e palavras não-oxítonas do primeiro grupo etimológico ("**-on**"), pronunciando-as como o "-o" átono nasalizado (`/ʊ̃ ~ ũ/`) em vez de `/-ãw̃/`. Neste dialeto pronunciamos as duas últimas palavras da frase "A volta dos que *não foram*" como `/nʊ̃ foɾʊ̃/` (ou até mesmo `/nʊ̃ foɾʊ/`, com a última vogal desnasalizada) em vez do padrão `/nãʊ̃ foɾãʊ̃/`.

### Realização ortográfica

A partir das etimologias, é possível identificar se uma palavra é escrita com ⟨-ão⟩ ou ⟨-am⟩ no português moderno pelas quatro regras ortográficas seguintes. Como qualquer regra ortográfica, estas só valem para palavras nativas. **Van** (ou **vam**, uma adaptação ortográfica muito usada, apesar de incorreta), da abreviação inglesa de *caravan* (um tipo de carro), foge desse regra, por não ser nativa.

1. Todas as palavras monossílabas são escritas com a terminação ⟨**-ão**⟩, independentemente da etimologia. Por exemplo: *"não, vão, cão, são, mão"*. No português moderno padrão, essas monossílabas não variam em tonicidade (são sempre tônicas), exceto nos dialetos que conservam os casos átonos (ver seção anterior).
2. Todas as palavras polissílabas oxítonas são escritas com a terminação ⟨**-ão**⟩, independentemente da etimologia. Por exemplo: *"fogão, estão, nação, alasão"*.
3. Todos os nomes polissílabos não-oxítonos são escritos com a terminação ⟨**-ão**⟩, independente da etimologia, devido às convergências ao terceiro grupo. Por exemplo: *"órgão, refrão, bênção, sótão"*.
4. Todas as palavras polissílabas não-oxítonas que não são nomes (todas flexões verbais) são escritas com a terminação ⟨**-am**⟩. Por exemplo: *"cantam, foram, enxáguam"*. Como esta terminação não é usada em nomes, ela é invariante em número nominal, ou seja, a terminação ⟨**-ans**⟩ para indicar plural não existe em palavras nativas, somente em estrangeirismos como *"vans, slogans"*.

Comment: Com algumas exceções como *órgão, orégão, bênção*.

Comment: De fato, esqueci desses casos. Mas todas essas paroxítonas com **-ão** são substantivos com plural **-ãos** (*órg**ãos***, *benç**ãos***, etc.).  A maioria dos substantivos com **-ão** têm plural **-ões**, e são todas oxítonas.  Vou adicionar essa exceção à resposta!

Comment: Que curioso, "enxaguam" não leva acento em Portugal... é paroxítona.

Comment: @ANeves, em todas as fontes que vi, usa-se *enx**á**guam*, com acento gráfico (e continua sendo paroxítona, pois o **⟨gu⟩** forma um dígrafo, resultando na pronúncia paroxítona trissillábica `/ẽɪ̯̃'ʃa.ɡʷɐ̃ʊ̯̃/`). Se a palavra não tivesse o acento gráfico, pela ortografia vigente, o acento padrão cairia sobre o **⟨u⟩**; e, nesse caso, **⟨gu⟩** não formaria dígrafo, e a pronúncia seria a paroxítona tetrassilábica `/ẽɪ̯̃.ʃa'ɡu.ɐ̃ʊ̯̃/`.

Comment: P.S.: Acabei de ver o texto da última (d̶e̶n̶t̶r̶e̶ ̶m̶u̶i̶t̶a̶s̶) reforma ortográfica. O Anexo 1º, Base 10ª, parágrafo 7º, cita explicitamente a conjugação do verbo enxaguar como sendo ambígua (vale tanto *enx**á**guam* quanto *enx**a**guam*). Apesar de que creio que a falta do acento gráfico implique na diferença fonética que mostrei acima.

Comment: É como dizes, Seninha, e firmas o teu argumento excelentemente! É uma diferença transatlântica, cá [não acentuamos](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=enx%C3%A1guam+site%3A.pt) a palavra, e lêmo-la *en·xa·GU·am*. O dicionário português Priberam [confirma](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/Conjugar/enxaguar).

Comment: Já tinha lido esta resposta, mas antes do teu longuíssimo edit. Há algumas polissílabas não-oxítonas em *-am* que não sejam verbos? Se não há a regra reduz-se a verbos são em *-am*, substantivos em *-ão*. Se há, não seria boa ideia dar exemplos?

Comment: Realmente, não há nomes não-oxítonos terminados em "-am" (ao menos não encontrei nenhum); o que é esperado já que a convergência dos não-oxítonos de outros grupos para "-ão/ãos" só afetou substantivos. Realmente, essa edição ficou bastante longa... Eu estava estudando mudanças fonéticas até que percebi isso e vim editar a resposta para adicionar a etimologia.

Answer (score 3):

A conjugação do verbo *ir* (vê a ligação [1] em baixo, clica em 'ver flexão') na 3.ª pessoa, plural, do Presente é *vão*.

A 3.ª pessoa, plural, do Futuro imperfeito é *irão*.

✤*vam* não parece existir (vê a ligação [2] em baixo). Na língua inglesa tens o substantivo *van* que nomea uma carrinha. ✤*estam* também não aparenta existir.

---

[1] http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?action=lemma&id=28493

[2] http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?sel=exact&action=simplesearch&base=form&query=vam